Is my question about intelligence a bad one?
My observation which I ask about in this question is not something I really expected people to like, but I did hope there would be some professionalism involved, considering the effort I put into focusing this on science, without bias or sexism.. I'm simply attempting to understand observed data with a genuine interest in the science.
I feel as if my question really shouldn't be voted down on this particular site, where the community is made up of scientist, or those interested in science, people of intelligence.
Is there anything wrong about my question? Why down votes after so much effort is seen in the question to avoid any confusion of discrimination? 

People downvote for a range of reason, but here's my take on it.
It's okay to ask questions about sex differences in intelligence or cognitive functioning. The main issue is that the question makes a lot of assumptions based on idiosyncratic experience in order to justify the rationale for the question. Furthermore, these assumptions reflect sexist stereotypes. If you make an assumption that could be construed as sexist, then there is an extra-obligation to have such claims be well supported by empirical research.
